# what is a convenient way of continuously editing a file of text

Tags: java, string

I am currently making a Java application that depends on VLC for media streaming.  In order to stream media using VLC a config file has to be made with all the media you want to stream in a specific format, like this:

> new MyVideo1 vod enabled setup 
>    MyVideo1 input *filepath*
>
> new MyVideo2 vod enabled 
>     setup MyVideo2 input *filepath*
>
> new MyVideo3 vod enabled 
>    setup MyVideo3 input *filepath*

So what I want to do in my program is to dynamically add or delete specific entries into this config file.  Keep in mind it the file has to keep this format. So if i want to delete the 2nd entry from the above example it would look like this:

> new MyVideo1 vod enabled setup 
>    MyVideo1 input *filepath*
>
> new MyVideo2 vod enabled 
>     setup MyVideo2 input *filepath*

Adding entries would just append to this file.  **My question is, is there anyway to quickly append and delete specific entries in this config file and keep this format?**

(A side note, you can add comments to this file using the '#' character)

Comment: IMHO, this is bad (very bad) design, you should try to find another way to send the info. Anyway, if it has to be done this way, I would create a dedicate server and create a new file for each new message; that way the writer process can open/write/close the file and later the reader can open/read/close/delete or rename

Comment: Yea, I agree that this is bad design. But this is how VLC media server works if you want to do video streaming. I dont like it as well.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a text file sitting on a hard drive somewhere.  If you look at some of the NIO classes in java, you should be able to dynamically edit this file.

The question becomes, what happens when VLC is reading the file while you're updating.  You'll need to come up with a way of preventing VLC from reading the file while you write to it.

If you can point VLC at a URL for the config file, then I'd use a servlet that serves the file.

Comment: The thing is that whenever you edit the config file you must restart the server in order for the changes to be applied.  Do you have any suggestions on how I can restart the server without affecting any clients?  I was thinking of maybe have a whole bunch of separate config files and running a server on each file. So if I every wanted to stop streaming an individual file I could just stop it's server without affecting others.

Comment: The you're really looking for answer from the VLC folks on how to do what you want, and not a java question.

Answer (score 0):

The comment character '#' you mentioned might be the best way of adding/removing lines from the file while preventing VLC from attempting to read while you're editing the file. The '#' character can then be deleted once the line is read-ready.

For deletion, the same idea applies.